Trying to connect a view model to a screen using Jetpack Compose for room database
I'm new to Jetpack Compose and I'm trying to pass in a view model to the screen, however I am unable to do so because I have an app navigation file which requires a parameter for the view model (though I'm not sure if it will work yet).
I was following a guide/tutorial which I was trying to get the room database to work: https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/learning-androids-room-database-made-easy-ada5906dcd59
Here is the view model code (incomplete atm):
@HiltViewModel
class EntryViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: DataRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private val _entries = mutableStateOf<List<Entry>>(emptyList())
    val entries: State<List<Entry>> = _entries
    init { loadEntryList() }
    private fun loadEntryList() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _entries.value = repository.getEntryFromDate()
        }
    }
}

Here is a snippet of the screen I'm passing the view model to
@Composable
fun AddJournalScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: EntryViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
// other codes
}

And here is the app navigation code with the
error.
I placed the view model variable on the main activity file
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    lateinit var navController: NavHostController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            FYPTheme {
                IntroductionScreen()
            }
        }
    }
}

Repository
Repo
Application
application class
Dao
dao interface
Database error message
database cannot be found
AndroidManifest
manifest file
I did not use fragments or activities(?) aside from the main activity class for my app.
I'm trying to pass in the view model to the addjournalscreen method so that I could save input details from users into the database (and eventually query it).
I've tried several online youtube videos and googling around and chatgpt but could not figure out how to do this as some of the videos that I tried to follow also comes up with this error in trying to pass in the view model.
I've also tried following some that used viewmodelfactory but I wasn't able to understand much of them.

The closing braces in MainActivity seem to be wrong. Can you correct them?

Sorry about that, I fixed it.

Try to use a dependency injection framework like hilt

I will try out the Hilt framework

@MicO I tried to use the hilt framework as you suggested, using a tutorial: https://medium.com/@chn_dr/room-dagger-hilt-jetpack-compose-material-3-d347046e8f61
However, there is an error when building the app which I've attached the error log, after some googling it seems to be some version error but the versions seems to be the same.

@xSea Try to use ksp instead
I'll make a comment on using ksp

Try using ksp
To set it up do the following
firstly, in your build.gradle(app) under the plugin section add these
plugins {
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
}

then in your dependencies add
dependencies {
    val daggerHiltVersion = "2.48"
    //Dagger - Hilt
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$daggerHiltVersion")
    ksp("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$daggerHiltVersion")
    ksp("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.1.0")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0")
}

then in your project build.gradle
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.0" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false
    id ("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.48" apply false
    id ("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.0-1.0.12" apply false
}

note that the ksp verson has to match your kotlin version

Hi,
It can now build but the app crashes this time round after trying to load the app. The only difference in the versions was the "com.android.application" version where mine was 8.2.0.
Could it be the view model coding that may be causing the problem?

What's the error message
Also how did you create your viewmodel and how did you instantiate it

Hi, I have added the error message as well as the codes on the post.

Did you annotate your MainActivity with
@AndroidEntryPoint

Ah yes, I forgot to add that on the post.

Did you add the class to your manifest file, i checked the link and didn't see where they ssid so. If you didn't add it, add it and try again

Do you mean the androidmanifest file? I'm not sure what class I'm suppose to add into it, but i've put in the manifest code image on the post just in case

Add these under the application tage on your manifest
<application
android:name=".DataBaseApplication

The app launches!
Although I'm not sure if the view model fully works until I figure out how to store user input into the database to test it out, but for the time being the app runs!
Thank you!

Hello, sorry for reviving the post again.
I just found out that trying to access the screen with the view model (AddJournalScreen) cause the app to crash whilst other screens are working fine. It came up with an error message "java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find implementation for com.example.fyp.EntryDatabase. EntryDatabase_Impl does not exist"

I think its better to make a new post concerning the issue
